# Printing out a table in console

Tags: java, console

This program prints out a table in the console. Suggestions for improvements are welcome.

**Example output**

```
Name             Sex      Age
Klaus Ulbrecht   male     12
Dieter           male     14
Ursula           female   16
```

[You can test and modify the program here.](https://repl.it/@Dexter1997/Textual-Table-View)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Main {
  private static List<List<String>> table; 

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    initTable();
    int spacing = 3;
    printTable(spacing);
  }

  private static void initTable() {
    List<String> row1 = Arrays.asList("Name", "Klaus Ulbrecht", "Dieter", "Ursula");
    List<String> row2 = Arrays.asList("Sex", "male", "male", "female");
    List<String> row3 = Arrays.asList("Age", "12", "14", "16");
    table = Arrays.asList(row1, row2, row3);
  }

  private static void printTable(int spacing) {
    List<Integer> maxLengths = findMaxLengths();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < table.get(0).size(); i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < table.size(); j++) {
        String currentValue = table.get(j).get(i);
        sb.append(currentValue);
        for (int k = 0; k < (maxLengths.get(j) - currentValue.length() + spacing); k++) {
          sb.append(' ');
        }
      }
      sb.append('\n');
    }

    System.out.println(sb);
  }

  private static List<Integer> findMaxLengths() {
    List<Integer> maxLengths = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<String> row : table) {
      int maxLength = 0;
      for (String value : row) {
        if (value.length() > maxLength) {
          maxLength = value.length();
        }
      }
      maxLengths.add(maxLength);
    }
    return maxLengths;
  }
}
```

Comment: is "being robust" one of your requirements?

Comment: I would say robustness is always a good thing! I am in the process of improving my code and adding a few features (CSV parsing, pseudo-graphics, etc.)

Comment: think what would happen if `List<String> row1 = Arrays.asList("Name", "Klaus Ulbrecht", "Dieter");` - heck, we lost *Ursula* ... that's even a harmless case... but if you forget an entry in `List<String> row2 = ...`  you are in serious problems ^^

Comment: have you considered the usage of existing classes, even though they may be kind of "misplaced" (heck, swing in console???), but maybe have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello and thank your for your code. I dont' know what kind of improvements you want but from an Object Oriented perspective I see some improvements.

The first one is to get rid of all the static methods and fields. You can easily move all your methods to an `AsciiTable` class with a `print(OutputStream out):void` method.

You can also use *arrays* instead of list and split the single argument to one for the columns titles and another for the content. This will clarify the initiliazation of your table.

```
Table table = new Table(
    new String[]{"Name", "Sex", "Age"},
    new Object[][]{
            {"Klaus Ulbrecht", "male", 12},
            {"Dieter", "male", 14},
            {"Ursula", "female", 16}
        });
```

As you can see I changed the order so that the cognitive load is reduced, by 
looking at the declaration we alrdeay have an idea of what are the titles and the content. We read for top to bottom, so it is more easier to have a declaration that already looks like that. This avoid your brain to switch the representation.

Another improvement that you can do is apply the *separation of concerns* principle by moving the "printing" away of the table. This is done easily with the *builder* where your `Table` is a director that drive a `Format`.

With this pattern you should be able to add another representation without changing the `Table`.

```
interface Format {
    void startHeader();
    void endHeader();

    void startBody();
    void endBody();

    void startRow();
    void endRow();

    void addColumn(Object value);
}

Format console = new Ascii(System.out, "   "); 
table.writeTo(console);
```

Now that your model (`Table`) is separated from the view (`Format`) you may discover that the model is quite simple and exists mainly to drive the view as the director in the builder pattern. But you can add new methods to filter or sort your table.

```
Table table = new Table(
    new String[]{"Name", "Sex", "Age"},
    new Object[][]{
            {"Klaus Ulbrecht", "male", 12},
            {"Dieter", "male", 14},
            {"Ursula", "female", 16}
    });
table.filter(1, "male"::equalsIgnoreCase)
     .sort(2, Comparator.naturalOrder())
     .writeTo(console);

Name             Sex    Age   
Klaus Ulbrecht   male   12    
Dieter           male   14
```

If you don't want to migrate to the object oriented way you can still improve the robustness of your code by dealing with empty columns or rows.

[1] Single Responsibility Priniciple is part of the S.O.L.I.D. acronym. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID

[2] When I speak about the builder pattern I refer to the creational pattern. Not the "fluent way of writing". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Printing arbitrary data as a table is a nice task of work for a utility function.

Such utility functions are usually defined in a utility class, which looks like this:

```
public final class Tables {
    private Tables() {}

    public static void print(List<List<String>> table, int spacing) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The name of the utility class usually takes the plural form of the main data ingredient. In this case that is a table, therefore `Tables`. The Java programming environment already defines similar utility classes named `Collections` and `Arrays`.

There is one important difference to your current code. All the variables needed by the `Tables.print` method are passed via parameters. There is no `static` field anywhere. This allows the `print` method to be called several times in the same moment and unambiguously lists all the data you have to provide when calling that method.

Citing from your code:

```
private static void initTable() {
  List<String> row1 = Arrays.asList("Name", "Klaus Ulbrecht", "Dieter", "Ursula");
  List<String> row2 = Arrays.asList("Sex", "male", "male", "female");
  List<String> row3 = Arrays.asList("Age", "12", "14", "16");
  table = Arrays.asList(row1, row2, row3);
}
```

You are mixing up the terms *row* and *column* here. A *row* in `initTable` will later be output as a *column* in `printTable`. That's confusing.

Several parts of your `printTable` method should be changed:

- The table should be passed as a parameter, instead of being a `static` field in the `Main` class.
- In the innermost `for` loop, the complicated expression is calculated several times, which is unnecessary. You should rather count from `k` downto 0: `for (int k = ...; k > 0; k--) { ... }`
- The final `System.out.println` prints 2 newlines. One of the may or may not be desired. In the latter case, replace the `println` with `print`.

In the `findMaxLengths` method:

- The table should be passed as a parameter, as above.
- Instead of the `if` clause, you can just write `maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, value.length());`